# Is there anything wrong with containing a php site in a single file?

Tags: php

I'm writing up an internal form management site in php and I've done it in a way where it is all contained within a single file with sections split up using variations of the below.

```
if (isset($_POST['NameOfSubmit'])) {/*section of site*/ ?> <div>Content</div> <?php;}
```

Is there anything wrong with doing it this way or should i be splitting off into seperate .php files?

Comment: I'd hate to have to try and debug anything in that...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'anything wrong'. In other words, what specifically are you concerned with?

Comment: Horrible to maintain and extend that kind of code

Comment: Nothing wrong, if you only start doing some coding and want to just `echo "Hello World"`. By the time you learn, you'll understand all the limitations of such approach.

Comment: Websites have a habit of growing larger than you ever planned for. Splitting pages out into separate files keeps the ever-growing pages manageable. It also avoids creating a single-point-of-failure in the site, when an issue in one part of the file destroys the entire site.

Comment: Jaxian, one of the concerns was server side performance if its having to load the entire site every page load. But if anyone has other considerations I'd be interested to hear them.

Comment: As long as it's really, really, really, really, *really*, **really** simple there's nothing *wrong* with that approach as such; well, apart from it being archaic, ugly and a nightmare to maintain/develop should you wish to do so... but if it's just a very simple standalone application that's never going to be developed or looked at by anyone else ... then you might just get away with it ;)

Comment: One thing I liked about doing it the way I have is it keepsparts of the site such as the header standardized, what do you think to doing it this way but instead of the content in the same page use include? eg

    if (isset($_POST['NameOfSubmit'])) {include "./section.php";}

Comment: Use some microframework instead to see how to create a proper website, because it looks like you're reinventing the wheel. Having the whole site in a single file is a sadistic approach at best.